# Seg Fault on getaddrinfo()

Tags: c++, c, sockets, segmentation-fault, bsd

I am getting a segmentation fault on my getaddrinfo call and cannot figure out why. It happens on both my server and client. Some code (server side) is -

```
class TcpServer {
public:

    TcpServer(int);
    ~TcpServer();

    void launchServer();

    void communicate();

private:
    const char* port;
    int fd;
    int comm_fd;
};
```

in tcpserver.cpp-

```
void TcpServer::launchServer() {
    int status;

    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *servinfo;  //will point to the results

    //store the connecting address and size
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    socklen_t their_addr_size;

    //socket infoS
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); //make sure the struct is empty
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;  //local address
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; //tcp
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     //use local-host address

    //get server info, put into servinfo
    if ((status = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", port, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }
```

in main-

```
TcpServer server(4950);
server.launchServer();
```

**The `int` passed to the constructor is casted to a `const char*` for port.**

When I run gdb, it gives me a backtrace of -

```
#0  0xb7dca737 in getaddrinfo (name=0x8054824 "127.0.0.1", 
    service=0x1356 <Address 0x1356 out of bounds>, hints=0xbffff20c, 
    pai=0xbffff234) at ../sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c:2080
#1  0x08050f79 in TcpServer::launchServer (this=0xbffff304) at tcpserver.cpp:25
#2  0x0804eae9 in main (argc=1, args=0xbffff3f4) at mainserver.cpp:47
```

So "Address 0x1356 out of bounds" makes me believe something is wrong with port, but I do not know what could be wrong. If anyone can point out something wrong I would be grateful. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Mixing two languages in the same source file is hard. I suggest you stick to one of C or C++ in your projects.

Comment: Your `port` argument to getaddrinfo is wrong. How do you initialize the `port` member of your TcpServer class ?

Comment: @pmg He's using C because he copied the necessary code from the man page.

Comment: @nos: he actually mentioned how (and you are right, he did it wrong). I've bolded that part so it's more clear what the error is.

Comment: @Sterling: Correct code should have very few casts. Avoid casting as much as possible, it is the exact cause of your problem here. Unfortunately, this is a habit which many people seem to develop as they learn about pointers :-/.

Comment: @Ariel: my compiler doesn't like `~` before an identifier, or `public:`, `private:` outside a switch. It also chokes on `class` and on `::` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", port, &hints, &servinfo)
                          ^
```

That should be a `char *`. I am guessing you are passing an integer and forcing the library to access an invalid address.

#### EDIT

In light of the comment of Blagovest Buyukliev I believe you are doing something like this in the constructor: `this->port = (const char*) port`.

You need to use something (`snprintf` maybe ?) to convert that integer to a `char *`. Simply **casting won't do**.

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev I think it's initialized the wrong way (using `=`)

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev: I've bolded the part where he specifies how he initialized the `port` member (and indeed that's where the mistake is).

Comment: @Evan: that's an important detail I overlooked :-)

Comment: @Evan Teran Indeed that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Are you supposed to be passing in `port` by reference rather than value, i.e. `&port`? 0x1356 is the same value as 4950 which is the port number you're trying to use.

**edit:** OK, I see it's supposed to be a string rather than a pointer-to-int. I'll leave my answer in place since it shows the port value is wrongly being interpreted as an address.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a pointer to port, but not allocating memory for it. (At least not that I can see in the code you listed.)

Port should be a string (i.e. char array), not a pointer to a char. And not an integer either.